# Can I make Django return the ID for a record on create?

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I'm using object.create to store a record to a django database:

```
     result = MyObject.objects.create(var1='foo',
                                      var2='bar',
                                         ...
                                     )
```

After this executes `result` is whatever string is returned by `__str__` (I confirmed this by changing it to `return self.id`). I'd like to have access to the primary key value, since the next step in some cases is to create another record which references this one via foreign key, but I'd really like `__str__` to return something more meaningful than that.

I realize that I could grab the most recently created, but this will be threaded code with multiple concurrent users, so there's a potential for that to fail in truly unfortunate ways.

I'm using an SQLite db for development, but will switch to MySQL for production, so if there's a way to solve this that requires mySQL I can make the switch now.

### Update - Never Mind

Okay, I figured out what was happening. On the first pass through the call to create doesn't happen, and while `result` was defined it wasn't an object.

Thanks, all. Digging further in response to your comments is what led me to find it.

< *slinking off embarrassed* >

Comment: How did you test what's the actual value of `result` - `print result` presumably?

Comment: are you calling `.save()` after create? in your case, `result.save()` and then the id of the record will be inside `result.id` - [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys)

Comment: @LatheesanKanes, `create()` does call `save()` internally.

Comment: [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) the primary key value of the record inserted should be inside `result.id`

Comment: @kroolik, yes, I'm essentially using a print. Since this is in a view, I send it to the page and add code to display it there.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes, I tried creating the object first then doing a save. I still get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'` when I try to reference `result.id`.

I looked in the docs you reference, but find to mention of the return value for `create()` or `save()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# No reporters are in the system yet.
>>> Reporter.objects.all()
[]

# Create a new Reporter.
>>> r = Reporter(full_name='John Smith')

# Save the object into the database. You have to call save() explicitly.
>>> r.save()

# Now it has an ID.
>>> r.id
1

# Now the new reporter is in the database.
>>> Reporter.objects.all()
[<Reporter: John Smith>]

# Fields are represented as attributes on the Python object.
>>> r.full_name
'John Smith'
```

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/overview/

Answer (score 0):

The action of calling `create` saves the new instance to the database. `result` now has a `pk` attribute which is its id.

Note that `result` is *the actual object*, not the result of `__str__`. Plus, you can use the object, rather than its ID, to set as a foreignkey of another object.

Comment: I'd be very happy if this was true -- I expected to get an object, but when I try to reference `result.pk` or `result.id` I get an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`.

When I changed the `__str__` method to point to `self.id` I got the id, which makes it seem like the `create()` method is itself returning the `__str__` value rather than the entire object.

Comment: I just tried removing `__str__` altogether; `result` comes back as an empty string.

Comment: Oh, and getting the object was definitely my first choice. I'm willing to settle for the key so I can query the db for the object, but of course avoiding unnecessary db access is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

result.pk should give you the primary key
“pk” is an alias to the field which is defined as the primary key.

Comment: I agree, it should. I wish it did. See my response to Daniel's post for more details.